# “Intrinsic beauty” auf Deutsch?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, mathematics

Wie übersetzt man am besten den Begriff *intrinsic beauty* ins Deutsche? Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob man dazu *intrinsische Schönheit, innewohnende Schönheit* oder etwas völlig anderes sagen sollte. Ein Beispielsatz wäre

> The mathematician loved mathematics for its intrinsic beauty.
>
> Der Mathematiker liebte die Mathematik aufgrund ihrer ____ Schönheit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Alt, aber noch brauchbar ist tatsächlich

> ...aufgrund der ihr innewohnenden Schönheit.

(Obwohl sich das schon ein bisschen geschraubt anhört)

Für Fremdwortliebhaber:

> ...wegen ihrer inhärenten Schönheit
>
> ...aufgrund ihrer substantiellen Schönheit
>
> ...aufgrund ihrer immanenten Schönheit

oder ganz einfach

> ...aufgrund ihrer inneren Schönheit.

oder

> ...aufgrund ihrer bleibenden Schönheit.

*wirklich*, *wahrhaftig*, *grundsätzlich* und *spezifisch* wären auch noch akzeptable Übersetzungen.

Comment: Oder innewohnend, oder intrinsisch. :)

Comment: @userunknown *intrinsische Schönheit* funktioniert vielleicht grade noch bei **Mathematik**. Aber hoffentlich wendet der Mathematiker dieses Attribut niemals auf seine Frau an... (Und *innewohnend* steht schon oben)

Comment: Sagt man denn auf englisch über eine Frau "instrinsic Beauty"?

Comment: Ich finde dem Begriff 'innewohnende Schöhnheit' wohnt doch eine gewisse Schönheit inne.

Answer (score 5):

Auch wenn es bereits eine akzeptierte Antwort gibt, würde ich als Übersetzungsmöglichkeit gerne noch

> ... aufgrund ihrer natürlichen Schönheit

vorschlagen. *Natürlich* ist zwar keine der typischen Übersetzungen von intrinsic, aber an dieser Stelle fände ich das Wort als deutschsprachiger Mathematiker durchaus passend.

Ansonsten finde ich

> ...aufgrund der ihr innewohnenden Schönheit.

auch in Ordnung.

Comment: Ach, eine akzeptierte Antwort sollte man nie als mehr als einen Zwischenstand versehen. Zusätzliche Antworten, die neue Seiten beleuchten, sind *immer* willkommen =)

Answer (score -1):

Bei dem Beispiel könnte man es auch so sagen:

> ... die Mathematik wegen der ihr eigentümlichen Schönheit.

Comment: Eigentümlich hat zwei Bedeutungen (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eigentuemlich), ich kenne es aber hauptsächlich in seiner Bedeutung als "merkwürdig".

Comment: Eigentümlich hat für mich tendenziell eine negative Bedeutung, was im Beispiel hier absolut unpassend ist.

Comment: In dieser Verwendung nicht.